# How to know the source of a link and load web app accordingly

Tags: flutter, web, flutter-web

I'm making an online ordering web app in Flutter, there's a link to the app on the restaurant website. The app needs to know which restaurant website the customer came from so that it can load the correct menu.

How would you do this? Webhook?

Answer (score 1):

I see two methods:

1. Referrer, Webbrowsers send a referrer-header. Maybe unstable for privacy browsers. [More information](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Referer)
2. Link-Parameter, give each resturant a unique link (with `your-app.com?source=mcdonalds`). [More information](https://www.fluttercampus.com/guide/52/how-to-get-parameters-from-url-in-flutter-web/)